# MongoDB - collection doesnt exist when searching in mongosh - but it DOES exist. Whats wrong?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

Im new to mongo.

I have created a db, collections and documents.

I installed mongosh and wanted to drop a collection from terminal.

When I initially created the db, I got as a default "test" db. I deleted it and created a custom one called appDB.

I can see in mongodb atlas that I DO have said db & collections & records.

First question: When I accessed my db form terminal I initially was in test db. I dont understand why it still seems to exist?

Also, I switched then into my appDB by typing

```
use appDB
```

all was good. then when I try any operstion on collection I get false (it doesnt exist). I also tried

```
show collections
```

which gives me empty space (so i guess doesnt exist.

I dont understand that as I am

1. connected to my appDB
2. I FOR SURE HAVE collections. What is happening inside mongosh?
   Thank you!!!

Comment: Did you specify the test database in the connection URI? What does **show dbs** indicate?

Comment: no I have removed test db from the URI and replaced it with appDB. I think I know why it happened, just not why. So when I run show dbs gives me: admin, config, local and users_test. That is actually my local db (I only use it to save db for testing). It doesnt seem to be conencted to my development remote db. I also been using 3t studio at the same time, but I just double checked (in case Im connected to the local db there which maybe interferes) and I am there connected to my remote appDB. How can I connect to the remote one from my shell?

Comment: Use the correct connection URI.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you Im good now :)

Comment: just another question:  I just noticed that when I run "use [db]" and add any random db, it seems like it accepts it as if that db existed. Now just as an experiment I run use blalaDB (which does not exist) and now im in blablaDB. Why is that so?!

Comment: MongoDB does not actually create a database or collection until you write data to it.